# R warning message - invalid factor level, NA generated

Tags: r

I have the following block of code. I am a complete beginner in R (a few days old) so I am not sure how much of the code will I need to share to counter my problem. So here is all of it I have written.

```
mdata <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv",colClasses = "character")
allstate <- unique(mdata$State)
allstate <- allstate[order(allstate)]
spldata <- split(mdata,mdata$State)
if (num=="best") num <- 1
ranklist <- data.frame("hospital" = character(),"state" = character())
for (i in seq_len(length(allstate))) {
    if (outcome=="heart attack"){
        pdata <- spldata[[i]]
        pdata[,11] <- as.numeric(pdata[,11])
        bestof <- pdata[!is.na(as.numeric(pdata[,11])),][]
        inorder <- order(bestof[,11],bestof[,2])
        if (num=="worst") num <- nrow(bestof)
        hospital <- bestof[inorder[num],2]
        state <- allstate[i]
        ranklist <- rbind(ranklist,c(hospital,state))
    }
}
```

**allstate** is a character vector of states.

**outcome** can have values similar to "heart attack"

**num** will be numeric or "best" or "worst"

I want to create a data frame **ranklist** which will have hospital names and the state names which follow a certain criterion.

However I keep getting the error

```
 invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I know it has something to do with rbind but I cannot figure out what is it. I have tried googling about this, and also tried troubleshooting using other similar queries on this site too. I have checked any of my vectors I am trying to bind are not factors. I also tried forcing the coercion by setting the hospital and state as.character() during assignment, but didn't work.

I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is apparently from a Coursera assignment I am not going to give you a solution but I am going to hint at it: Have a look at the help pages for `read.csv` and `data.frame`. Both have the argument `stringsAsFactors`. What is the default, true or false? Do you want to keep the default setting? Is `colClasses = "character"` in line 1 necessary? Use the `str` function to check what the classes of the columns in `mdata` and `ranklist` are. `read.csv` additionally has an `na.strings` argument. If you use it correctly, also the `NAs introduced by coercion` warning will disappear and line 16 won't be necessary.

Finally, don't grow a matrix or data frame inside a loop if you know the final size beforehand. Initialize it with the correct dimensions (here 52 x 2) and assign e.g. the i-th hospital to the i-th row and first column of the data frame. That way `rbind` is not necessary.

By the way you did not get an error but a warning. R didn't interrupt the loop it just let you know that some values have been coerced to `NA`. You can also simplify the `seq_len` statement by using `seq_along` instead.

Comment: Hi!    Thanks a lot for your reply. Your suggestions worked and the direct assignment worked much better, giving the results I was looking for. Also using `na.strings` got rid of the `NAs introduced by coercion`, though I still think I don't know how to use it perfectly. I will certainly read more about correctly importing data from files. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.